# Write the current paragraph to temp file in Vim

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to write a function to write the contents of the current paragraph the cursor is on to a temp file. In normal more  `vip:w!temp.txt<cr>` works fine, but placing `normal! vip:w!unidecode.txt<cr>` within a function doesn't seem to.

Any ideas on a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "clean" way is to avoid normal if possible. So simply

```
'{,'}write foobar
```

Comment: Thank's so much. This is exactly it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just to give the alternative:

```
:normal! vip:write file
```

Should work (there should be an implicit finish for the `:` I believe). If not, alternatives are

```
:execute "normal! vip:write file\<cr>"
```

and

```
:normal! vip
:'<,'>write file
```

You can see why avoiding normal mode commands in Ex is simpler :)